# Adding click event listener to button and changing value of varible that is only related to clicked button

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have group of button that are selected and added event listener with for loop,when each button are clicked I want to toggle style of it and also set a variable that is related to the clicked button to whether true or false.I am able to toggle their style in for loop but is there a way to toggle that variable in same loop instead of adding event listener to each button seperately?
My code is:

```
    document.getElementById("orderalert1").addEventListener("click", function () {  
    m = !(m != false) })

    document.getElementById("orderalert2").addEventListener("click", function () {  
    l = !(l != false) })

    document.getElementById("orderalert3").addEventListener("click", function () {

    k = !(k != false) });

    document.getElementById("orderalert4").addEventListener("click", function () {

    j = !(j != false) });

    document.getElementById("orderalert5").addEventListener("click", function () {

    n = !(n != false) });

    document.getElementById("orderalert6").addEventListener("click", function () {

    o = !(o != false) });

    var is=document.querySelectorAll(".select");

    function toggle(){for(var i = 0; i < is.length; i++){ is[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        this.classList.toggle("done"); }); }}

    toggle();
```

Comment: Can you store all variables in an object? something like `myVariables = {m: m, n: n, o: o}`?

Comment: check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/sfLdzvc3/

Comment: thank you for your answer,but I couldnt make it worked.when I tried your code,it takes allVariables object's properties "m","n","o" and toggle them false/true,but this process doesnt affect the m,n,o variables,they arent got toggled false/true,which is what I want,because I am going to need this m ,n, o variable to initiate alerts in the rest of the code if they are set to true.I may not be able to explain my problem properly,or couldnt pull it off from your code,sorry for that,I am beginner at web development.

Comment: I understood that. That's why I asked u in my first comment whether you can store them in allVars map. You have to access variables through that map only in order to use my code.